# Why the where clause of limiting the data time range is not precise in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I organize the `where` condition poart of query statement in Apache IoTDB like this: `where time>2022-08-09 08:30:41 and time<2022-08-09 08:40:41`. However, the actual result returned is `time >= 2022-08-09 08:30:41` while the other part is correct. Why did this happen and how should I adjust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your data unit for time is the same as your query statement unit for time. Seems like you may have smaller time unit for your data than your query statement (for example, milliseconds for your data, and seconds for your query statement). Try to unify these two units in Apache IoTDB and query again.